# something like an "extended" C string library?

Tags: c, string

I have used several dynamically typed languages and I have been avoiding C but enough is enough, it's the right tool for the job sometimes and I need to get over it.

The things I miss working with C are associative arrays and large string libraries. Is there a library that gives more options then string.h? Any general advice when it comes to make the transition with strings?

Comment: are you absolutely restricted to C? C++ has Boost (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/string_algo.html).

Comment: Aren't the things you're talking about the reasons you *would* use a different language than C?

Comment: Hi Andrew C++ scares me. I understand it but I think it will take me years to be fluent in it-Patrick

Comment: @Patrick: You gotta get over that mentality, or you won't survive as a developer. Languages are tools. Nothing more.

Comment: "it's the right tool for the job sometimes and I need to get over it." - if you're in need of a large string library, I'd suggest it's not the right tool for the job on this occasion.

Comment: @Alan: True, but the OP is correct when he says "it will take years to be fluent in it".

Comment: the beauty of C is that it is small and easy to remember.  you can use it once every few years when a task needs speed.  a few better optional extended libraries---indeed, strings and associative arrays---would go a long way making it even better.

Answer (score 10):

You can take a look at the [Better String Library](http://bstring.sourceforge.net/). The description from the site:

> The Better String Library is an
>   abstraction of a string data type
>   which is superior to the C library
>   char buffer string type, or C++'s
>   std::string. Among the features
>   achieved are:
>
> - Substantial mitigation
>     of buffer overflow/overrun problems
>     and other failures that result from
>     erroneous usage of the common C string
>     library functions
> - Significantly
>     simplified string manipulation
> - High
>     performance interoperability with
>     other source/libraries which expect
>     '\0' terminated char buffers
> - Improved
>     overall performance of common string
>     operations
> - Functional equivalency with
>     other more modern languages
>
> The
>   library is totally stand alone,
>   portable (known to work with gcc/g++,
>   MSVC++, Intel C++, WATCOM C/C++, Turbo
>   C, Borland C++, IBM's native CC
>   compiler on Windows, Linux and Mac OS
>   X), high performance, easy to use and
>   is not part of some other collection
>   of data structures. Even the file I/O
>   functions are totally abstracted (so
>   that other stream-like mechanisms,
>   like sockets, can be used.)
>   Nevertheless, it is adequate as a
>   complete replacement of the C string
>   library for string manipulation in any
>   C program.

Answer (score 5):

POSIX gives you [`<string.h>`](http://www.unix.com/man-page/posix/7posix/string.h), [`<strings.h>`](http://www.unix.com/man-page/posix/7posix/strings.h) and [`<regex.h>`](http://www.unix.com/man-page/posix/7posix/regex.h).
If you *really* need more of a string library than this, C is probably not the right tool for that particular job.

As for a hash table, you can't get a type-safe hash table in C without a lot of nasty macros.
If you're OK with just storing `void`-pointers, or with doing some manual work for each type of map, then you shouldn't be lacking for options. Coding your own hash table is a hoot and a half - just search Stackoverflow for help with the hash function. If you don't want to roll your own, [`strmap`](http://pokristensson.com/strmap.html) [LGPL] looks decent.

Answer (score 2):

[GLib](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/) provides many pre-made data structures and string handling functions, but it's a set of functions and types completely separated from the "usual" ones, and it's not a very lightweight dependency.

If instead C++ is a viable alternative for your task, it bundles a string class and several generic containers ready-made into the standard library (and much other related stuff can be found in Boost).

Comment: I know that the last paragraph will bring the downvotes of the hardcore C users. :)

Comment: I think the first paragraph (recommending glib) would bring more downvotes from hardcore C users, but I'll refrain... :-)

Answer (score 1):

What specifically are you looking for in your extended c-string library?

One way to get better at C, is to create your own c-string library. Then make it open source, and let others help refine it.

I don't usually advocate creating your own string libaries, but w.r.t. C, it's a great way to learn C.

Comment: Hi Alan I actually don't really have a problem to solve, just trying to get my head around the language, thanks again

Comment: Actually I think making your own string (or whatever data structure) library is about the worst approach to learning C. It's a good way to learn about implementing higher-level languages, but if you really want higher-level general-purpose data structures, you should probably be using an existing higher-level language. The only time C shines is when you actually use C idioms, and "high level strings" is not a C idiom.

Answer (score 1):

I've not used it myself, but you should at least review the SEI/CERT library [Specifications for Managed Strings, 2nd Edition](http://www.sei.cmu.edu/library/abstracts/reports/10tr018.cfm).  The code can be found at [CERT](http://www.cert.org/secure-coding/managedstring.html).

Answer (score 1):

Much of the power of C consists of the ability to have direct control over the memory as a sequence of bytes. It is a bit against the philosophy of the language to treat strings as something higher-level than that.

I would recommend rolling your own very basic one. It will be an enlightening experience especially to learn pointer arithmetics and loops.

For example, learn about ["Schlemiel the Painter's algorithm"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schlemiel_the_Painter%27s_algorithm) regarding `strcat` and design your library to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

An associative array associating string keys and struct values in C consists of:

- A hash function for strings
- An array with a prime number of elements, inside each of which is a linked-list head.
- Linked-list elements containing `char *` pointers to the stored keys and (optionally) a `struct *` pointer to the corresponding value for each key.

To store a string key in your associative array:

- Hash it modulo that prime array size.
- In that array bin, add it to the linked-list.
- Assign the value pointer to the value you are adding.

Comment: @Patrick, I hope you understand what I'm getting at: roll your own.  It's a small file when you're done.